# gganimate with multiple points for same x value

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have some data in which multiple y coordinate values for a single x coordinate value. It is similar to the one included in this question. It also has a `state` variable which has to be used for the `transition_state()` function in `gganimate`.

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(
  x = seq(11),
  type1 = c(2, 3, 2.5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 2),
  type2 = c(NA, 3, 3.5, 3, NA, NA, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, NA)
)
m.df <- melt.data.table(df, "x", variable.name = "grp")
m.df[x %in% seq(5), "state" := 1][x %in% seq(6, 11), "state" := 2]
m.df
#>      x   grp value state
#>  1:  1 type1   2.0     1
#>  2:  2 type1   3.0     1
#>  3:  3 type1   2.5     1
#>  4:  4 type1   3.0     1
#>  5:  5 type1   2.0     1
#>  6:  6 type1   2.0     2
#>  7:  7 type1   3.0     2
#>  8:  8 type1   2.5     2
#>  9:  9 type1   3.5     2
#> 10: 10 type1   3.0     2
#> 11: 11 type1   2.0     2
#> 12:  1 type2    NA     1
#> 13:  2 type2   3.0     1
#> 14:  3 type2   3.5     1
#> 15:  4 type2   3.0     1
#> 16:  5 type2    NA     1
#> 17:  6 type2    NA     2
#> 18:  7 type2   3.0     2
#> 19:  8 type2   3.5     2
#> 20:  9 type2   4.0     2
#> 21: 10 type2   3.0     2
#> 22: 11 type2    NA     2
#>      x   grp value state
```

The data is plotted using gganimate as shown below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(m.df, aes(x, value, group = grp, color = grp)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = T) +
  geom_point(na.rm = T) +
  theme_bw()
```

The plot can be found [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0THYM.png)

I want to use the gganimate `transition_state()` function using the state column in the data as shown below, but shows an error.

```r
library(gganimate)

ggplot(m.df, aes(x, value, group = grp, color = grp)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = T) +
  geom_point(na.rm = T) +
  transition_states(state)
#> Error in rep(seq_len(nrow(polygon)), splits + 1): invalid 'times' argument
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to make your code work is to group by both `grp` and `state` using e.g. `interaction`. Otherwise `gganimate` fails to split your data by `state` as both states are present in each group. Additionally, you have to put the `group` aes after the `color` aes. Otherwise you run in to the same issue:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(m.df, aes(x, value, color = grp, group = interaction(grp, state))) +
  geom_line(na.rm = T) +
  geom_point(na.rm = T) +
  transition_states(state)
```

[image]